# I need some insight into dealing with the variance of a product of random variables

Tags: probability

I have a pretty weak background in random variables and statistics, and what I do have is very formal. I can brute force some of the derivations I need with a lot of effort and review of class notes, but I lack any real insight into whether my result is useful.

Basically, I have some gyroscope/accelerometer package with who knows what variance or distribution, but the method is more important than my particular implementation, so I'm just assuming that it's Gaussian noise, and I'm going to estimate some constant variance based on the data.

I need to use this data with another source of telemetry which is mounted to a rigid body with mine, so I'm using $a_t = a_m + \omega' \times r + \omega \times (\omega \times r)$, where 
$a_t$ = transformed acceleration vector
$a_m$ = measured acceleration vector
$\omega$ = measured gyroscope vector
$\omega'$ = first derivative of the gyroscope reading
$r$ = the displacement vector between the accelerometer/gyro and the point I want transformed to.

I can get the derivative with a Savitsky-Golay filter, which is a nice linear combination of Gaussians. However, the terms in the cross product are ugly non-Gaussian distributions.

I could try and find the new contrivance matrix, but I'd like to use my result with a Kalman filter. Is there some way to come up with a "worst case" Gaussian that would encompass the new distribution, but with added uncertainty?